# Move camera in respect of finger position Opengl

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

This is my first approach to androids opengl and I have stuck in moving my rendered object with finger. 
Actually, everything works but when I try to move object really fast it loses its coordinates.

My object is hexagonal grid built by calculating coordinates for 6 vertexes. First of all I handle on touch event and check if map is grabbed:

```
 switch(action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mapTouched = hexMapRenderer.isMapTouched(ev);
                int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);
                downX = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, pointerIndex);
                downY = MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, pointerIndex);
                moveX = (int)downX;
                moveY = (int)downY;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(!hexMapRenderer.isScaling()) {
                    if(mapTouched) {
                        hexMapRenderer.setMapMoving(true);
                        hexMapRenderer.moveMap((int) (moveX - ev.getX()), (int) (moveY - ev.getY()));
                        moveX = (int) ev.getX();
                        moveY = (int) ev.getY();
                    }
                }
                break;
```

Inside my method `moveMap` I calculate position of my hexagons:

```
   public void moveMap(int shiftX, int shiftY) {
        for(int i = 0; i < hexMap.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < hexMap[i].length; j++) {
                if(hexMap[i][j] != null && hexMap[i][j].isToDraw()) {
                    hexMap[i][j].setCenterPoint(new Point(hexMap[i][j].getCenterPoint().x - shiftX, hexMap[i][j].getCenterPoint().y - shiftY));
                }
            }
        }
        this.shiftX = shiftX;
        this.shiftY = shiftY;
    }
```

And inside `onDrawFrame` method I move map like this:

```
 if(mapMoving) {
     gl.glTranslatef(-shiftX, -shiftY, 0f);
 }
```

As I mentioned everything works great when I move map slow and gently but when things are getting too fast it looks like that position of rendered object doesn't equals calculated position from moveMap method. 
Do you have any solutions how to achieve smooth moving of object in opengl? I've tried recalculate position and redraw whole object but when map starts to move it flickers. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your world coordinates might not be the same as your touch screen coords.

Comment: Actually I use `glOrthof` in my `onSurfaceChanged` to map world coordinates with screen coordinates.